# Unable to find element using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium:: I have to find an element in my webpage, When I inspected that element it came as below

```
<A class=navBarBottom2 href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();">SIGN ON</A>
```

"SIGN ON" is a link and my selenium is not able to click on it.

I'm using Java and implementing to run in IE. I was using this code

```
// click on sing on
diver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = 'javascript:document.forms[0].submit();']")).click();
```

Comment: Show your code. What language? What browser is Selenium using? How are you locating the element?

Comment: I'm using java language and Implementing for IE. Please find my code here // click on sing on
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = 'javascript:document.forms[0].submit();']")).click();

Answer (score 2):

Your XPATH is wrong: It should have been `".//a[text()='SIGN ON']"`
else use `driver.findElement(By.link("SIGN ON"))` to locate element

Comment: The leading `.` isn't really needed, though it might slightly speed up the search.

Comment: the leading period is to search from current root context which in this case would be root html. If this worked for you then can you accept this as answer so that anyone else searching for similar question can find answer easily